# UITableViewController<UISearchBarDelegate> not Calling the UISearchBarDelegate methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard, uitableview, uisearchbar

Given the following `UITableViewController`, why can't I get any of the `UISearchBarDelegate` methods to be called? I'm omitting the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OpportunitySearchViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>
@end

#import "OpportunitySearchViewController.h"

@interface OpportunitySearchViewController ()
@end

@implementation OpportunitySearchViewController
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"initWithCoder:");
    };

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"self=%@ self.view=%@ ", self, [self view]); 
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];

    NSLog(@"viewDidUnload");
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    NSLog(@"shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:");

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"searchBar:textDidChange:");
}
@end
```

I've confirmed that my Storyboard scene is configured to use the `OpportunitySearchViewContoller` class and I've confirmed that the `UISearchBar` on the scene has the First Responder set as it's delegate. Although that might be wrong, but I couldn't find a File's Owner in the Storyboard interface.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the search bar in your cell? plz show us code in "tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:" method.

Comment: Try to create an outlet for you search bar and wire it to the search bar in storyboard and set the delegate in program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't connect the first responder to your class as the delegate. Drag from the search bar to the controller object itself and make that the connection to the `delegate`.